# OrderByDescending in Lambda expression?

Tags: linq

Below is my code where I want to get order by values of the date. Can anyone help me out to get solution for that ?

```
pointsCore.Categories
          .Where(d => d.EventCount != WebUi.NOCOUNT)
          .SelectMany(c => c.Events)
          .Select( x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.EventDate)
                               .ToString("MMM"))
          .Distinct()
          .ToList();
```

Comment: What do you want order by descending ? Events list ?

Comment: I was order by descending

Answer (score 3):

Sure - just add it *before* you convert to a string month name:

```
pointsCore.Categories
          .Where(d => d.EventCount != WebUi.NOCOUNT)
          .SelectMany(c => c.Events)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate)     // <-----------
          .Select( x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.EventDate)
                               .ToString("MMM"))
          .Distinct()
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a LINQ `OrderByDescending` on your `EventDate`:

```
pointsCore.Categories.Where(d => d.EventCount != WebUi.NOCOUNT)
          .SelectMany(c => c.Events)
          .OrderByDescending(d => d.EventDate)
          .Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.EventDate).ToString("MMM"))
          .Distinct()
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort before you convert to the string format. I would also do the distnict before the sorting and formatting:

```
pointsCore.Categories
        .Where(d => d.EventCount != WebUi.NOCOUNT)
        .SelectMany(c => c.Events)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(ev => ev.EventDate)
        .Select( x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.EventDate)
                           .ToString("MMM"))         
        .ToList();
```